# How to use @JsonUnwrapped in list of objects

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON object using Jackson annotation, but I can't deserialize it:
Is an array of a type "Deposito"

```json
{
  "depositos": [
    {
        "deposito": {
            "id": "13168775373",
            "nome": "Geral",
            "saldo": "100000.0000000000",
            "desconsiderar": "N",
            "saldoVirtual": "100000.0000000000"
        }
    }
  ] 
}
```

my java class:

```
@JsonUnwrapped
@JsonProperty(value ="depositos")    
private List<Deposito> depositos;
```

my deposito class:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "deposito")    
public class Deposito {
    
    private String id;
    private String nome;
    private Double saldo;
    private String desconsiderar;
    private Double saldoVirtual;
}
```

Comment: It is possible to mantain the same class structures if you modify your in json in `{"depositos": [{"id": "13168775373","nome": "Geral","saldo":"100000.0000000000","desconsiderar": "N","saldoVirtual": "100000.0000000000"}, 
    ]
}`, is your json immodifiable ?

Comment: My json is immodifiable it is from a crazy supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add an additional class to your model:

```java
public class DepositoMetadata {
    private Deposito deposito;
}
```

Now you need to adjust your main java class (as you called it):

```java
private List<DepositoMetadata> depositos;
```

Finally, you can remove `@JsonRootName(value = "deposito")` from your `Deposito` class.

Comment: Like this way, with a wrapper class, I already used, but I'd like to use without it.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no simple and clean way to do this. Unless you want to write your own custom deserializer just for this. I would not recommend it. Add the `DepositoMetadata` class and then map the complete model to your internal model. That is my suggestion.